# How can I get the windows "Type" of a file with only the file extension in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet where i have a list of file extensions for files, a logical file size, and a physical file size. This is the only information I have for every file in the list. basic example :

.txt 100 80

.txt 120 90

.mpg 2444 2000

What I would like to do is use VBA to get the windows type of a given file extension. (ie, in the image below .CAB = 'Security Catalog', .dll = 'Application extension', and so on)

(I don't have enough reputation to post an image. Link here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xqax.png)

Comment: A file extension is more or less a convenience thing and doesn't always reflect a certain filetype, especially on *nix. For example, I could name text file text.jpg.

Comment: I think you're looking for the "Default Application" for the file extension. which should be stored in the registry. [more](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-29533.html)

Comment: I think you're [looking for this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileDescriptions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of file extensions and descriptions, and I'm not sure where to get a nice list...but if you have a couple, you can add them manually.

The following code assumes your data (i.e. `.txt 100 80`) starts in cell A1.  This puts the description you give in cell B1 (or the cell directly to the right):

```
Sub test()
Dim i&, lastRow&
Dim fileExt$
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    With Cells(i, 1)
        fileExt = Trim(Left(Cells(i, 1), WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", Cells(i, 1).Value)))
        Debug.Print fileExt
        Select Case fileExt
        Case ".txt"
            Cells(i, 2).Value = "Text File"
        Case ".mp4"
            Cells(i, 2).Value = "Mpeg 4"
        Case ".mpg"
            Cells(i, 2).Value = "Mpeg"
        End Select
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

If you have a huge list of extensions and descriptions, you could instead probably use an array to do this, or create a table and use Vlookup instead.  Just kind of depends on how much you want to manually type.